# image not showing inside webpage, but works outside

Tags: php

Please take a look at this URL

[http://www.viewpromocode.com/product/redmi-3s-prime-silver-32-gb-4/](http://www.viewpromocode.com/product/redmi-3s-prime-silver-32-gb-4/#)

It has a broken image in it, but if you open the image in another tab, it work !!

why ?

I am using the following image compression script.
It is even generating correct thumbnails, but the it is loading inside the webpage.

https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize

Comment: I for one will not visit any URL's. Post your code in your question.

Comment: the href to the picture is `/content/img/example.php?img=http://www.viewpromocode.com/content/uploads/images/product_57b546be73b33.jpg` make it `http://www.viewpromocode.com/content/uploads/images/product_57b546be73b33.jpg`

Comment: I see how are comments are being completely ignored; I should have expected that.

Comment: @Fred -ii , that is the easy way. But I was trying to add an image compression script here. linking the image directly is not the method I like.

Comment: If and when any of those links/URL's cease to exist, your question will no longer be valid.

Comment: @ShijilT Always try to make sure the question exists only on Stack Overflow, as soon as people have to visit other domains you are usually not going to get quality answers from respected users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script http://www.viewpromocode.com/content/img/example.php returns html:

```
<div><img src='cache/c21956c960fbdb93479e8be09d6ee057_w144.jpg' border='0' /></div>
```

instead image content

Comment: Livach, I have removed the div and img attributes fro example.php, flushed server cache ...s till it give html result.

Comment: @ShijilT you are using the library wrong. Read the instructions carefully. `example.php` is just and example how the library is used and is not supposed to be used in production.

Comment: i just replaced the script with another simple one. Now it works.